# Utilizing journey data in AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

This is a simple question but I simply can't find an answer anywhere. I have a journey that is currently using a Data extension that is updated daily from an automation, and in AMPscript I need to use a value from said DE that's gonna differ for each contact entry in the journey, is it possible to simply set it like this `SET @var1 = [fieldname]`?

Appreciate any feedback :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch data from your sendable data extension in three ways:

- simply using `%%fieldname%%`
- using `%%=AttributeValue("fieldname")=%%`
- setting an ampscript variable: `SET @var1 = AttributeValue("fieldname")`

First option is a quick one, when you just want a quick inline personalisation, like `<h1>Hello %%first_name%%</h1>`. The drawback of this solution: it will throw an error, if your email is sent to a data extension not containing a field with that name.

Second option, which also is for inline personalisation `<h1>Hello %%=AttributeValue("first_name")=%%</h1>`, is more robust. It will not throw an error if sent to a data extension without this field, but simply return an empty string.

Lastly, if you want to use your field for further Ampscripting, you can set the value of an Ampscript variable, from the `AttributeValue("fieldname")` function.

Comment: So and this is simply a personal question to remove my doubts(sorry I'm new to SFMC and AMPscript) using ``AttributeValue("fieldname")`` in an AMPscript will use the values from the DE without me having to refer to it simply because it's already referred in the journey?

Comment: @GuilhermeSantos So, every email being sent - be it from a journey, a scheduled send, etc. requires a sendable data extension. This will have a number of fields, a.o. email address, subscriber key etc. It does not have anything to do with the journey as such. Just if this data extension has a field called "fieldname", you will be able to reference it in your ampscript by using AttributeValue function.